# SolrCloud becoming slow over time

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a `3 node` SolrCloud setup (`replication factor 3`), running on `Ubuntu 14.04` `Solr 6.0` on SSDs. Much indexing taking place, only softCommits. After some time, indexing speed becomes really slow, but when i restart the solr service on the node that became slow, everything gets back to normal. Problem is that i need to guess which node becomes slow.

I have 5 collections, but only one collection (mostly used) is getting slow. Total data size is `144G` including tlogs.

Said core/collection is `99G` including tlogs, tlog is just 313M. Heap size is `16G`, Total memory is `32G`, data is stored on SSD. Every node is configured the same.

What appears to be strange is that i have literally hundreds or thousands of log lines per second on both slaves when this hits:

```
2016-09-16 10:00:30.476 INFO  (qtp1190524793-46733) [c:mycollection s:shard1 r:core_node2 x:mycollection_shard1_replica1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [mycollection_shard1_replica1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={update.distrib=FROMLEADER&update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema&distrib.from=http://192.168.0.3:8983/solr/mycollection_shard1_replica3/&wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[ka2PZAqO_ (1545622027473256450)]} 0 0
2016-09-16 10:00:30.477 INFO  (qtp1190524793-46767) [c:mycollection s:shard1 r:core_node2 x:mycollection_shard1_replica1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [mycollection_shard1_replica1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={update.distrib=FROMLEADER&update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema&distrib.from=http://192.168.0.3:8983/solr/mycollection_shard1_replica3/&wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[nlFpoYNt_ (1545622027474305024)]} 0 0
2016-09-16 10:00:30.477 INFO  (qtp1190524793-46766) [c:mycollection s:shard1 r:core_node2 x:mycollection_shard1_replica1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [mycollection_shard1_replica1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={update.distrib=FROMLEADER&update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema&distrib.from=http://192.168.0.3:8983/solr/mycollection_shard1_replica3/&wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[tclMjXH6_ (1545622027474305025), 98OPJ3EJ_ (1545622027476402176)]} 0 0
2016-09-16 10:00:30.478 INFO  (qtp1190524793-46668) [c:mycollection s:shard1 r:core_node2 x:mycollection_shard1_replica1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [mycollection_shard1_replica1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={update.distrib=FROMLEADER&update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema&distrib.from=http://192.168.0.3:8983/solr/mycollection_shard1_replica3/&wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[btceXK4M_ (1545622027475353600)]} 0 0
2016-09-16 10:00:30.479 INFO  (qtp1190524793-46799) [c:mycollection s:shard1 r:core_node2 x:mycollection_shard1_replica1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [mycollection_shard1_replica1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={update.distrib=FROMLEADER&update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema&distrib.from=http://192.168.0.3:8983/solr/mycollection_shard1_replica3/&wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[3ndK3HzB_ (1545622027476402177), riCqrwPE_ (1545622027477450753)]} 0 1
2016-09-16 10:00:30.479 INFO  (qtp1190524793-46820) [c:mycollection s:shard1 r:core_node2 x:mycollection_shard1_replica1] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [mycollection_shard1_replica1]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={update.distrib=FROMLEADER&update.chain=add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema&distrib.from=http://192.168.0.3:8983/solr/mycollection_shard1_replica3/&wt=javabin&version=2}{add=[wr5k3mfk_ (1545622027477450752)]} 0 0
```

In this case `192.168.0.3` is the master.

My workflow is that i insert batches of 2500 docs with ~10 threads at the same time which works perfectly fine for most of the time but sometimes it becomes slow as described. Ocassionally there are updates / indexing calls from other sources, but it's less than a percent.

**UPDATE**

Complete config (output from Config API) is http://pastebin.com/GtUdGPLG

**UPDATE 2**

These are the command line args:

```
-DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks
-DSTOP.PORT=7983
-Dhost=192.168.0.1
-Djetty.home=/opt/solr/server
-Djetty.port=8983
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/var/solr/log4j.properties
-Dsolr.install.dir=/opt/solr
-Dsolr.solr.home=/var/solr/data
-Duser.timezone=UTC
-DzkClientTimeout=15000
-DzkHost=192.168.0.1:2181,192.168.0.2:2181,192.168.0.3:2181
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50
-XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000
-XX:ConcGCThreads=4
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8
-XX:NewRatio=3
-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/opt/solr/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 /var/solr/logs
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4
-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90-Xloggc:/var/solr/logs/solr_gc.log
-Xms16G
-Xmx16G
-Xss256k
-verbose:gc
```

**UPDATE 3**

Happened again, these are some Sematext Graphs:

Sematext Dashboard for Master:
[image: Sematext Dashboard Master]

Sematext Dashboard for Secondary 1:
[image: Sematext Dashboard Secondary 1]

Sematext Dashboard for Secondary 2:
[image: Sematext Dashboard Secondary 2]

Sematext GC for Master:
[image: Sematext GC Master]

Sematext GC for Secondary 1:
[image: Sematext GC Secondary 1]

Sematext GC for Secondary 2:
[image: Sematext GC Secondary 2]

**UPDATE 4 (2018-01-10)**

This is a quite old question, but i recently discovered that someone installed a cryptocoin miner on all of my solr machines using [CVE-2017-12629](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2017-12629) which i fixed with an upgrade to 6.6.2.

If you're not sure if your system is infiltrated check the processes for user `solr` using `ps aux | grep solr`. If you see two or more processes, especially a non-java process, you might be running a miner.

Comment: What hard commit interval do you have configured?

Comment: Hi Peter, i attached the complete config, the hard commit interval is 180 sec, soft commit interval is 45 sec

Comment: Are hard and soft commits only happening automatically, or are you also triggering softCommits as a part of your indexing process?

Comment: It's also critical to understand the nature of the slowdown.  When you monitor the slow node, are you seeing GC pauses, I/O spikes, or CPU spikes?  How much heap memory is Solr using on a slow node vs an unloaded one?

Comment: @Stefan,  why is mergeFactor is set to -1? Its been sometime since I worked on Solr, but from what I rem the default is 10, and this parameter decides how often segments are merged.

Comment: Also do you have any performance monitoring on your servers? Do you see a spike in CPU, Memory, disk space, swap size? I have used Sematext in the past. They have a 30 day free trial. https://sematext.com/spm/integrations/solr-monitoring/  . Once installed I would keep an eye on Memory and number of segments. My guess is that too many segments try to merge together, eating up memory and in turn slowing your servers down.

Comment: @PeterDixon-Moses I/O Spikes are up to 100%, usually about less than 20%, CPU is not very loaded, `top` shows around `2-4`. GC Pauses have not been monitored yet, will do when this happens next time.

Comment: @jay it's the default value that i got from `bin/solr bootstrap`

Comment: @jay swap is disabled. Memory is, as said, `32G` and no OutOfMemory errors. Heap Size is set to `16G` max, but at most `10G` is used. GC is `UseConcMarkSweepGC`

Comment: Just installed sematext on one of my nodes, will install on the other two later. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @Stefan, A couple of questions. 1. Can you paste a screenshot of this page http://your_server:8983/solr/#/cloud 2. Are you using Solr in schemaless mode? That would explain these lines in the log "add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" . 3. Can you paste a copy of your schema file - for the collection which slows down? 4. Can you paste a few sample queries? Are you using group_by or facets in your queries? 5. Do you have a load balancer in front of these nodes? Or are you sending all queries to one of the nodes? 6. Are all 3 machines identical in hardware? (Cpu, memory, disk space, etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you're seeing disk I/O hitting 100% during indexing with a high-write throughput application.

There are two major drivers of disk I/O with Solr indexing:

1. Flushing in-memory index segments to disk.
2. Merging disk segments into new larger segments.

---

If your indexer isn't directly calling `commit` as a part of the indexing process *(and you should make sure it isn't)*, Solr will **flush** index segments to disk based on your current settings:

- Every time your RAM buffer fills up (`"ramBufferSizeMB":100.0`)
- Based on your 3 min hard commit policy (`"maxTime":180000`)

---

If your indexer isn't directly calling `optimize` as a part of the indexing process *(and you should make sure it isn't)*, [Solr will periodically **merge** index segments on disk](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/02/visualizing-lucenes-segment-merges.html) based on your current settings (the default merge policy):

- `mergeFactor: 10`, or roughly each time the number of on-disk index segments exceeds 10.

---

Based on the way you've described your indexing process:

> 2500 doc batches per thread **x** 10 parallel threads

... you could probably get away with a larger RAM buffer, to yield larger initial index segments (that are then flushed to disk less frequently).

However the fact that your indexing process

> works perfectly fine for most of the time but sometimes it becomes slow

... makes me wonder if you're just seeing the effect of a large **merge** happening in the background, and cannibalizing system resources needed for fast indexing at that moment.

---

**Ideas**

- You could experiment with a larger `mergeFactor` (e.g. 25).  This will reduce the *frequency* of background index segment merges, but not the resource drain when they happen. (Also, be aware that more index segments often translates to worse query performance).
- In the indexConfig, you can try overriding the default settings for the `ConcurrentMergeScheduler` to throttle the number of merges that can be running at one time (`maxMergeCount`), and/or throttle the number of threads that can be used for merges (`maxThreadCount`), based on the system resources you're willing to make available.
- You could increase your `ramBufferSizeMB`.  This will reduce the frequency of in-memory index segments being flushed to disk, also serving to slow down the merge cadence.
- If you are not relying on Solr for durability, you'll want `/var/solr/data` pointing to a **local** SSD volume.  If you're going over a network mount (this has been documented with Amazon's EBS), there is [a significant write throughput penalty](https://gist.github.com/ktheory/3c3616fca42a3716346b), up to 10x less than writing to ephemeral/local storage.

Comment: This is also an interesting read about a similar situation which (though it's a bit old now) may yield additional ideas:  https://www.hathitrust.org/blogs/large-scale-search/forty-days-and-forty-nights-re-indexing-7-million-books-part-1

Comment: Peter, thanks, will monitor a bit more and then make some changes if it doesn't get better. I'm not calling `softCommit`, `commit` or `optimize`. I only rely on the `autoSoftCommit` and `autoCommit` values. You say that `mergeFactor` defaults to 10, but my default config (from `bin/solr bootstrap`) has `mergeFactor = -1` .. What does this mean?

Comment: -1 is just the value those variables get initialized to internally (code tests for -1 and if seen, uses the default values).

Comment: I added some sematext charts, maybe this helps clarify what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the CPU load of each core of the master and not only the combined CPU graph ? What I noticed is when I index with Solr when Xmx is too small (could be the case if you have 144GB data and Xmx=16GB), when the indexing progresses, merging will take more and more time.
During merging, typically one core=100% CPU and other cores do nothing.
Your master combined CPU graph looks like that: only 20% combined load during sequences. 
So, check that the merge factor is a reasonable value (between 10 and 20 or something) and potentially raise Xmx.
That's the two things I would play with to start with.
Question: you don't have anything special with your analyzers (custom tokenizer, etc) ?

Comment: If you mean, custom `fieldTypes` then yes. Basically for searching substrings case insensitive. I achieve this by, for example, `solr.NGramFilterFactory` with `minGramSize=2` and `maxGramSize=60`

Comment: And no, i don't have the CPU load per core.

Comment: If you do "htop" on the master machine and see that during long periods, there is only one core at 100% (during the same time the Solr interface is not responsive), then you may want to raise the Xmx. Changing the merge factor can also make a difference. If neither solve totally the problem, then, it is something else, but that what I would do first.

Comment: That's what i'm seeing. Is there any way to calculate a more or less specific heap size? I'm currently using 16GB of 32GB total. These machines are dedicated servers and nothing else will be running on them. Also SWAP is turned off.

Comment: Looking at the size of your data (200M docs and 144GB data) and the size of your server RAM (32GB), raising Xmx will probably help, but your data is still big. Do you have a single shard ?

Comment: Yes, one shard with three replicas.

Comment: Do you recommend another shard/replica setup with 3 dedicated nodes?

Comment: when you say 99GB data, this is for a single replica or total ? If it is for a single replica, and since you have 32GB servers, I believe you need sharding. The merging in a 99GB index will be slow. Raising Xmx should help, but sharding is necessary I think. It should improve indexing and search response times.